# What format does HttpBrowserCapabilities.MinorVersion return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I have several browsers on my machine and would like to test the HttpBrowserCapabilities.MinorVersion return value.

I cannot find details as to whether a minor version of 1 (e.g., browser version 3.1) would be returned as 1.0 or 0.1. All of the browsers on my machine are .0 versions, so I haven't been able to produce a test that will answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this on my current machine but the minor value of for example, 3.1, will return 0.1.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332783%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). In the C# example, they have defined a double and are adding the major to the minor to provide the version.